# Finding conversion rate from events DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

| user | id | time | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2021.12.12 10:08:39:399 | viewed |
| a | 2 | 2021.12.12 10:08:39:402 | clicked |
| a | 3 | 2021.12.23 3:43:19:397 | viewed |
| a | 4 | 2021.12.23 3:47:11:131 | viewed |
| a | 5 | 2021.12.30 19:20:31:493 | viewed |

How would I go about trying to find the conversion rate grouped by each user? By this I mean the
percentage of views that are followed up by a click within a certain timeframe (lets say 30s). In this case user *a* has viewed four times and clicked once, with the click being in the allotted
timeframe - giving us a conversion rate of 1/4 = 25%.

I tried doing this by splitting the frame by event then using `pd.merge_asof()` which works for most cases but sometimes user id's are replaced by nulls and sometimes not all viewed events are carried over into the new table. Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
# Convert the `time` column to Timestamp, which make time calculation a lot easier
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S:%f")

# Sort the dataframe
df = df.sort_values(["user", "time"])

# Definition of success
success = (
    df["user"].eq(df["user"].shift())   # same user as previous row
    & df["event"].eq("clicked")         # current row is "clicked"
    & df["event"].shift().eq("viewed")  # previous row is "viewed"
    & df["time"].diff().dt.total_seconds().lt(30) # time difference is less than 30 secs
)

# Assemble the result
result = (
    df.assign(is_view=lambda x: x["event"].eq("viewed"), success=success)
    .groupby("user").agg(
        views=("is_view", "sum"),   # count number of views
        success=("success", "sum")  # count number of successes
    ).assign(
        rate=lambda x: x["success"] / x["views"]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse clicked to 1 and viewed to 0 and then do a groupby with sum and count aggregations. Afterwards you divide the count column from the sum column and get your result.

```py
df # your data

df["success"] = df["event"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "clicked" else 0)

results = df.groupby("user").agg({'success' : ['sum', 'count']})

results["conversion"] = results["sum"] / results["count"]
```

Comment: Your method would give the right answer in this case but it doesn't take into account the timeframe constrictions

Comment: This answer does not count `success` correctly. It count `success = number of clicks`. The question defined 2 conditions: a `clicked` must follow a `viewed`, and "within 30 seconds of the viewed"